Javascript fetch() API call triggers CORS preflight
I'm implementing a "javascript FETCH() API" call in my front end; but once the code runs it triggers an error:

Access to fetch at https://saavn.dev/api/search/songs?query=promise from origin https://544444465te.com has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

The javascript code:
function SearchSongs() {
  const SearchSong = document.getElementById('Search').value.toLowerCase();
  // Saavn API endpoint for searching songs
  const saavnSearchUrl = 'https://saavn.dev/api/search/songs';

  const params = {
    query: SearchSong,
  };

  // Request headers
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

  // Make the GET request to search for songs
  fetch(`${saavnSearchUrl}?${new URLSearchParams(params)}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((songData) => {
      playlist.innerHTML = '';
      for (const song of songData.data.results) {
        const songName = song.name;
        const artistName = song.primaryArtists;
        const highestQualityDownloadUrl = song.downloadUrl.find(
          (downloadUrl) => downloadUrl.quality === '320kbps',
        );
        const image150x150 = song.image.find(
          (image) => image.quality === '150x150',
        );
        const lowestQualityImage = song.image.find(
          (image) => image.quality === '50x50',
        );
        playlist.innerHTML += `<li class="list-group-item" onclick="playSong('${highestQualityDownloadUrl.link}','${image150x150.link}'>
                <img src="${lowestQualityImage.link}">
                ${songName} by ${artistName}</span>
                </li>`;
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error));
}

I tried to add the CSRF token in the headers but the error persisted.
What is the problem ?

What does the network inspector say? What's the actual response?

@deceze it says:  await fetch("https://saavn.dev/api/search/songs?query=skyrim", {
"credentials": "omit",
"headers": {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0",
"Accept": "/",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site"
},
"method": "OPTIONS",
"mode": "cors"
});

Yeah, nah. Look at the network tab of the developer tools, and look at the actual request being sent and its response. If it says "not ok status", then what status does it have and what's its response body, where it may tell you about particular error reasons?

GET requests have no body and therefore do not require a content-type header, so why are you adding one? If you remove that, your request becomes simple and will probably work though it looks like the API in question only partially supports CORS

In fact, I'm curious. Adding a content-type header to GET requests or even making it a default header in all requests is so prevalent in Stack Overflow questions that there must be some extremely popular tutorial out there spreading this frankly terrible advice. Is there any chance you could provide links or references to whatever guide, tutorial or documentation that you're following?

@deceze it has no status; just a "none" sign.

@phil I'm implementing this tutorial:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/music-player-using-django/ I'm customizing the javascript for my site

You should leave a comment on that article explaining how it's wrong or suggest an improvement

@Phil thank you tons, I removed the "content-type" like you said and it's fetching songs now from the endpoint; I will write to geeksforgeeks.com
